# node can't find modules that exists in parent node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, docker, require

I am using node 0.12.0 with express and created a Docker image.
This is my directory structure:

```
-server/
    -config/
        -config.js
    -app.js
    -package.json
    -node-modules/
        -deep-extend/
            -...
            -...
            -...
```

My package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    ...
    "deep-extend": "^0.3.2",
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

and `config/config.js` looks like:

```
var deepExtend = require('deep-extend');
...
...
...
module.exports = deepExtend({}, .....);
```

I have an issue running this app. When running it with `node server/app` I got and error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'deep-extend'
```

When running the following, the problem solved and `node server/app` runs fine:

```
cd config
npm install deep-extend
```

When is the problem?
Why node doesn't look on parent folder for node_modules?

Comment: `cd server` and `npm install`

Comment: @latheefitzmeontv: Come on, I did it. server has node_modules folder.

Comment: Is there still error?

Comment: @latheefitzmeontv: Yes.

Comment: oh k.. then provide `sudo npm install deep-extend` from `cd server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this I had to add the node_modules folder into my NODE_PATH environment variable.